# Detecting Multiple Filters of Same Type on a Magento Category Page

Tags: php, magento, filter, categories

I am looking to add or remove content from a Magento site based on which filters are being applied. Specifically, detecting when filters of the same type are being applied.

For instance, if items from a sports store can be sorted by league, I am looking to detect if NBA and NFL are selected filters. I can successfully detect if one league is being filtered for using something like this:

```
$_filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

if (is_array($_filters)) {
   foreach ($_filters as $_filter) {
      $filterName = $_filter->getName();
      $filterLabel = $_filter->getLabel();
   }
}
```

I was unable to loop through and detect multiple filters from the same category (in this case, League), because it seems to only add one filter per type. Is there another method for detecting applied filters that would help with this situation?

Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not that you can't detect it, the problem is that magento doesn't handle multi-selection for a specifiv filter. Coding it is possible though but it's a little bit of work ... Maybe there is a free add-on for this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plugin Mana Filters will allow you to do what you want ,

You can use Mana Filters Modules that will allow you to have multiple filters from same type, then you can loop etc .. !

http://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing, something like this plugin and some tweaks will probably be the best bet, but details would be helpful. On the install I am using there is the [Amasty Layered Navigation](http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html) plugin, but I have not found documentation for anything of this nature with either plugin.

Comment: To be able to use multiple filters you need to rewrite the layered navigation and how it manipulate the data, and this is what Mana filters achieved. I have used amasty layered navigation. so you need to look the layered navigation rewrites in
Block/Layer/.. and Model/Layer/..

Comment: I'll be using the Mana Filters on another site, thanks for the link.